# Problem regarding filling squares inside a $n\times n$ grid.

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, game-theory

> Assuming a $n\times n$ square grid, what is the most number of squares that can be filled in such that there are no completed rows, columns, or diagonals?

Is there a formula to calculate this?

Real world example:

> Given a Bingo sheet, what is the most spots you can mark and still *not* win a bingo?

It stands to reason that since $N$ is finite, there much reach a point where it is *impossible* to fill any additional positions such that you would not complete a row, column or diagonal.

> Problem is, how do we calculate or predict this number?

Comment: Do you mean just the two largest diagonals, or any maximal diagaonal?

Comment: The two largest, initially, but both would be nice to know.

Comment: By the way, regarding my comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/568066/filling-a-grid-so-as-not-to-completely-fill-and-row-column-or-any-diagonal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Hint:

Flip the problem around: what's the smallest number of empty squares you need to have an empty square in every row, column, and diagonal? Can you find a simple, symmetric configuration to do it with $n$ of them when $n$ is odd? Is it possible to use fewer?

What if $n$ is even? If $n$ is even and greater than $2$, how can you modify a simple odd solution to give an even one?

#### Expansion:

Consider the case where you want all the little diagonals too. Certainly it's sufficient to blank out the top row and both left and right columns for $3n-2$ blanks. Is this optimal? For $3\times 3$, it certainly is. For larger boards, it's not clear to me. Things are again different if the board is pasted over a torus. I'm sure these questions have all been studied, but I don't know the answers.

Comment: By manual elimination I have figured that a 3x3 grid is 6, and a 4x4 is 12, but what If I had grids of significantly larger numbers like 19 or even 100?

Comment: It seems to hold that the formula could potentially be M = n(n-1) where n is the size of the grid.

But does this hold true for larger grids?

Comment: Flipping the problem, it would stand that we would want to ensure at most 1 filled square in each rank, file, and diagonal. Most efficient way to do this on an odd board is to simply populate one of the two largest diagonals, as the center space would satisfy the other diagonal.

Comment: for even boards (where N =/= 2) the same would apply, but you would need to ensure the center 4 tiles are filled on the opposite diagonal from the 4 outermost tiles. the rest would simply be peppered across to achieve efficient coverage.

Comment: You are right. For a board of N=2, it is a special case and would require three squares to be filled, breaking the above formula....

Comment: @JaredTritsch, for the even case, just populate one of the two largest diagonals, and then rotate the two in the center! No peppering is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

$n(n-1)$ is the answer.Think of a  Latin square with even diagonals having all distinct numbers. How does any random number come in that. it comes in a way that there are no complete row, column and diagonals. The empty squares that do not have one in them, can never in any way align to give a complete diagonal, row or column.
 Hence $n(n-1)$ is the maximum number of squares and $n! - 2$ are the number of ways in which these squares can be selected from a square grid. If any more squares are selected from this grid then there will obviously be a complete diagonal, row or column or both.